# How to make websockets to go through a proxy in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, websocket, push-notification

**Generalizing** that would be the question... how to make websockets to go through a proxy in node.js?

**In my particular case** I'm using pusher.com with the [node.js client library](https://github.com/abhishiv/pusher-node-client) they recommend. Looking inside the code I would like to know some hints on what I should change in order to make this library to work with a proxy... you can take a look in the code [here](https://github.com/abhishiv/pusher-node-client/blob/master/lib/pusher-node-client.js#L146-147)

Maybe I should somehow replace or modified the [websockets module](https://github.com/abhishiv/pusher-node-client/blob/master/lib/pusher-node-client.js#L8) that is being used by the library?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answers/comments! A couple of things to take into consideration (excuse me if I'm wrong with some/all of them, just learning):

- I don't want to create a proxy server. I just want to use an existent proxy server within my company in order to proxified my websockets requests (particularly pusher.com)
- Just to let you know, if I use a proxifier like the one for windows [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) and I set up the rule to inspect for all connections to port 443 to go through the proxy server *proxy-my.coporate.com:1080 (type SOCKS5)* it works like a charm.
- But I don't want to go this way. I want to **programatically** configuring this proxy server within my node js code (even if that involved to modified the pusher library I mentioned)
- I know how to do this for HTTP using [Request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) (look for the section that mentions how to use a proxy).

  - I want a similarly thing for **websockets**.

Comment: you can use pusher's http features to interact in nearly the same way as sockets, if nothing else...

Comment: You are right about inspecting the websockets module... it should the CONNECT method on a configured proxy. Where does that module live?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I've expanded my question.

Comment: If it helps you can check [socket.io-proxy](https://github.com/ymx/socket.io-proxy), which is a library build on top of websockets.

Comment: @dandavis in pusher.com I only found HTTP REST API for server side... for client side (which is what I want, to wait for events in a channel) I didn't find anything.

Comment: @razvan I tried that library but it fails with error Error: found error in socket.io-proxy - error is: Error: socket hang up
Error: socket hang up
    at SecurePair.error (tls.js:1013:23)

Comment: Also I tried with the node module https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-https-client but it doesn't support wss protocol...

Comment: @SantiagoAgüero Hi mate, did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 11):

From
https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent

```
var url = require('url');
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

// HTTP/HTTPS proxy to connect to
var proxy = process.env.http_proxy || 'http://168.63.76.32:3128';
console.log('using proxy server %j', proxy);

// WebSocket endpoint for the proxy to connect to
var endpoint = process.argv[2] || 'ws://echo.websocket.org';
var parsed = url.parse(endpoint);
console.log('attempting to connect to WebSocket %j', endpoint);

// create an instance of the `HttpsProxyAgent` class with the proxy server information
var options = url.parse(proxy);

var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(options);

// finally, initiate the WebSocket connection
var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint, { agent: agent });

socket.on('open', function () {
  console.log('"open" event!');
  socket.send('hello world');
});

socket.on('message', function (data, flags) {
  console.log('"message" event! %j %j', data, flags);
  socket.close();
});
```

Comment: It works using this method,thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using a proxy for websockets should work roughly the same as for https connections; you should use the CONNECT method. At least that's what both the [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.9) and [HTML5](http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html) specs say. So if your proxy implements CONNECT, you're good to go.

Comment: @Chris Wesseling  I know this is more than a year later... I have implemented a node proxy using http and net modules and it works fine with both http and https. However, my socket.io programs fail.  How do I get socket.io to use wss as opposed to ws? Thats for my reverse proxy. Now for the forward proxy, how do I use sites using socket.io if they are not using wss and my forward proxy has no express support for websockets?

Comment: @samir Your comment looks like 2 questions. Try asking them and reference this question or my answer as related research you've done. Starting a new thread in the comments is considered bad form.

Comment: @Chris Wesseling Fair enough. I have posted a new question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394338/websockets-through-a-custom-node-based-proxy]

Answer (score 2):

Try [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)

It allows you to send http or websocket requests through a proxy.

```
var http = require('http'),  
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
//
// Create a basic proxy server in one line of code...
//
// This listens on port 8000 for incoming HTTP requests 
// and proxies them to port 9000
httpProxy.createServer(9000, 'localhost').listen(8000);

//
// ...and a simple http server to show us our request back.
//
http.createServer(function (req, res) {  
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(9000);
```

Source: [link](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-intro/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'll try this out... I was reading a little bit and stumbled upon this other stackoverflow [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716915/node-js-good-webserver-with-websocket-proxying-ssl-support?rq=1) which also reference the library you're saying. If you can expand with a concrete example or using node-http-proxy with websockets applicable for pusher.com it will be appreciated.

Comment: afaict this *implements* a proxy and doesn't explain how opening a socket through a proxy works. Can you point me to something I'm missing?

Comment: Well, you can simply use the websocket protocol with the proxy (wss://) and you're proxying websockets!

Comment: I don't think this answers the question... This simply adds an extra middle man. It doesn't show how to connect to a remote ws endpoint through a proxy. OP - did you work out a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Most web proxies don't support websockets yet. The best workaround is to use encryption by specifying wss:// (websocket secure protocol):

```
wss://ws.pusherapp.com:[port]/app/[key]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rudolf! I'm quite confuse... in my question I've posted a link to the code that interacts with the pusher api which uses the encryption wss:// as your're saying, Am I missing something in order to make it work behind a proxy server?

Comment: The other answers here seems to assume you're trying to setup your own node.js proxy for your websockets. Is your problem that your end-users are behind proxy servers and their browsers are therefore unable to establish a connection? Do you have any control over the proxy or know which version it is?

Comment: Correct. My problem is that I have to use a corporate proxy in order to be able to connect to the pusher web socket endpoint.

Comment: Using ssl works because it will use the CONNECT method. If in your code you do the same, you get the same result. I expect wss: will trigger the same timeouts that @dandavis [mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23747424/383793#comment-36602761).