# how to do a proxy for a websocket in Node

Tags: node.js, npm, websocket, middleware

In Node I was able to do a `http` proxy in the following way:

```
https://localhost:443 -> http://localhost:8100
```

with the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
...
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    httpProxy.createServer({
        target: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 8100,
        }
    }).web(req, res);
});
...
https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(443, function(){
    console.log('App running on port: 443');
});
```

But I also need to do a similar redirection for a web socket in the following way:

```
wss://localhost:8107 -> ws://localhost:8100
```

Do you have any idea on how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686379/how-to-make-websockets-to-go-through-a-proxy-in-node-js

Comment: can you review the answer @davidesp? leave a comment if it didn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

The `http-proxy` module [supports websockets](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#proxying-websockets)

Just do:

```
httpProxy.createServer({
  target: 'ws://localhost:8100',
  ws: true
}).listen(8107);
```