# Fiddler not capturing Websocket request sent in Node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, fiddler

Im new to Javascript and Node.js , and am having trouble setting up a websocket in Node.js

Running the following command in Chrome console worked just fine, with an entry showing up in Fiddler 4:
`new WebSocket("wss://example.com/ws");`

However when running (as a .js file):

```
var WebSocket =require('ws');

let socket = new WebSocket("wss://social.krunker.io/ws");

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
};
```

, The output is the same but there is no entry in Fiddler .

I have tried setting the environment variables by:

```
set http_proxy http://127.0.0.1:8888
set https_proxy http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a very similar question which is a bit older: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23686379/150978 Have you read it?