# sending a websocket request through a proxy server in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, proxy

Is it possible to use a proxy server with a websocket client in nodejs?

I tried:

```
import httpsProxyAgent from 'https-proxy-agent';
import W3CWebSocket from 'websocket';

const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/', {
  agent: new httpsProxyAgent("http://LOGIN:PASS@IP:PORT")
});
```

I have given a lot of combinations to websocket client, but I have no idea why it doesn't work.

*obviously i don't mind another websocket client!

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686379/how-to-make-websockets-to-go-through-a-proxy-in-node-js)?  How relevant is it to what you're trying to do?

Comment: I haven't seen this post, that's exactly what I meant! Thank You